# Comment field override

Tags: comments

i have a strange problem with altering comment text field in single post.

I've created `$fields =  array()`. Inside this array, besides other fields, I've also added:

```
'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'New Label', 'noun' ) . '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>'`,
```

based on Wordpress documentation.

I expected from WP to override current Comment field with mine, but instead it just displayed the one i added in code and kept the old one.

Does anybody have any idea why the system is behaving like this?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the entire function call? It's not 100% clear what you're doing from just a snippet of an array, I'm assuming this is in a `single.php`? Which function are you passing this parameter to?

Comment: Hi Tom, nope it's inside comments.php, but i solved the issue. Actually, comment_field should be outside the $fields array. It is treated separately from the group of other fields.

So, when i call comment_form(), i have to pass $fields array as one argument and then comment_field as another one. This way the system will override the default comment field.

Comment: Can you post your answer as the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, comment_field should be outside the $fields array. It is treated separately from the group of other fields. So, when i call comment_form(), i have to pass $fields array as one argument and then comment_field as another one. This way the system will override the default comment field.